# rdlc report alternative for .net core 2.0+

Tags: .net-core, reporting, rdlc

After doing some google searches, and checking some projects on github I came to know there is no support for rdlc report in .net core. May be I am wrong, Is there any way to at least generate pdf with rdlc report defination(like in .net4.5 mvc)? We have a large project with rdlc reporting and we are now migrating to .net core but stuck on it. Is there any way(or may be 3rd party library or something) to do it? Or any other solution to replace rdlc? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find any answer? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can find the solution [here](http://blog.geveo.com/IntegratingRDLCReportsToNetCoreProjects)  or try this [GitHub repo](https://codeload.github.com/tharindubuddhi/netcorerdlc/zip/master)